# React useEffect restarting timer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have been trying the useEffect hook and have come across a problem that I don't know to fix.

I have written a simple counter example which uses setTimeout within useEffect to update values.

```
        if (countState.stopWatch === 0) {
            dispatch({ type: 'reset' });
        }
        else {
            const timeId = setTimeout(() => {
                console.log("Timeout " + JSON.stringify(countState));
                if (countState.stopWatch > 0) {
                    dispatch({ type: 'decrement_stopwatch' });
                }
            }, 1000);

            return () => {
                clearTimeout(timeId);
            };
        }
    });
```

The code works ok but has one problem. When the function is being rerendered, it causes the timer to exit and be set up again which causes gaps (i.e. the timer is not running every 1 sec but every sec plus time to re-render the app).

When I use a class based solution, I run the timer in the class constructor and the timer runs smoothly as it is not cancelled by re-rendering.

Any ideas as to how I get round this in the functional version?

The full code including the function and class based solutions can be found here:

https://github.com/jmc420/react_examples/blob/master/counter/hooks_counter/src/StopWatch.tsx

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-countdown-hook

Comment: How come you chose to use setTimeout for the functional one but setInterval for the class one? If you use setInterval in the functional comp, you'd make your life a lot easier

Comment: No particular reason for using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to rack my brain to come up with a way to use `setTimeout` like you were trying to do in a functional component but like you realised, there is an issue with the tiny bit of time between rendering and resetting the timeout.

The best I could come up was to just use `setInterval`. If you weren't sure how to use that with hooks, I made a quick Codesandbox with my experiments: https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-shape-rjmjs

The key here is that we set the interval once and only remove it on unmount so it is ticking away consistently.

For the first one, we do all the logic inside of where set state call because this intrinsically has access to the most recent state args to avoid issues where the interval is closed over the initial state like:

```
setCount(c => {
  // c is the most recent count state
  if (c > 0) {
    return c - 1;
  }
  return c;
});
```

If that doesn't meet your needs, I added a second one as well where it uses a ref to bypass the closure problem as well. We just call the function assigned to the ref each interval tick but we reassign what that function is each render.

```
timerLogicRef.current = () => {
  if (otherCount > 0) {
    setOtherCount(otherCount - 1);
  }
};
```

It might be easier to make the second fit with your reducer set up.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the solution is. If useEffect is used without dependencies, you get a warning from react but the timer does not exit when the timer decrements. You then get the problem Of referring to out of date closure variables, but this is fixed by using useRef.